# Como obtener la suma del total de Sale.order.line donde uno de sus campos sea igual

Tags: odoo, odoo13

Estoy utilizando Odoo 14 la versión Enterprise y me he encontrado con un problema que no logro resolver...

El sistema que se esta realizando es para una constructora que realiza presupuestos, y cada presupuesto puede tener diferentes subcontratistas...

El campo de subcontratista esta dado de alta en sale.order.line y lo que quiero lograr es obtener el total de todos los productos agrupados por subcontratista, para este valor después usarlo en un contrato(PDF) que se genera en sale.order.line

Aquí muestro los presupuestos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el sale.order.line, cada detalle tiene su subcontratista, en este caso es Jesus Rivera y como podemos ver son dos trabajos que están asignados a ese subcontratista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aquí muestro el Subcontratista, es un selected del modelo de Contacto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy intentando lograr es que al darle imprimir Contrato de Trabajo, independientemente el Trabajo que sea vea quien es el subcontratista, y jale toda la información que corresponda a ese subcontratista en este caso el Total de las líneas... esto para obtener la suma y poder mostrarlo en el pdf.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en Odoo, he estado investigando pero estoy perdido, he intentado hacer un nuevo modelo, pero no he logrado el resultado, o usar query pero al no conocer la base de datos no he tenido avance...

¿Me podrían orientar como resolver este problema?

Gracias.

Comment: Lamento informarte que esto es una comunidad de programadores, no de soporte de Odoo. Si tienes un problema con el código, te invito a que muestres el código y qué problema tienes... si tienes un problema con las herramientas de Odoo, creo que lo mejor sería que preguntes en alguno de los sitios donde se da soporte a Odoo!

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo tu pregunta, en el sale.order.line debes agregar un campo calculado y que te traiga sumado todos los demás valores del mismo subcontratista.

Para ello se puede crear un campo calculado de la siguiente forma:

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model): #Crear una clase herencia
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'   #Indicas que hereda de sale.order.line

    total_sub_contratista = fields.Float("Subcont. Total", compute='_compute_sub_contratista')

    def _compute_sub_contratista(self):
        # En esta linea debes hacer un search 
        # para obtener todos los registros del mismo subcontratista 
        # y luego sumarlos. 
        lista_otros_totales = self.env['sale.order.line].search([('subcontrat_id','=',record.subcontrat_id.id)]) #No se como se llaman tus campos, debes buscar sobre el mismo campo con el dato que tienes de tu registro actual.
        suma = sum([x.total_sub_contratista for x in lista_otros_totales]
        for record in self:
            record.total_sub_contratista = suma
```

Espero te sirva, saludos...!!!